# Validation rule with 4 criteria

Tags: validation, administration

Hello below is my criteria for validation rule on field name TSP__c

- Starting with “TSP”,
- Then 6 alpha numeric ,
- Then “-“,
- Then 1 alpha numeric,
- Then 1 numeric

e.g. TSPXXXXXX-X2

Regular expression is `REGEX( {!TSP_Code} , "TSP[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}").`

Any idea how can i make validation rule using this criteria?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you have the regex mostly sorted. What research have you done? What have you tried? If you're getting an error, include the entire error message **verbatim**. If you're using this in a validation rule, and it is successfully saving, then try testing your regex with something like regexr.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your validation rule is far too verbose. For example, `{1}` isn't necessary, because it's the default value to match on. You should be able to something like this:

```
TSP(?i)[a-z\\d]{6}-[a-z\\d]\\d
```

I suspect your problem is that you're forgetting that a validation rule triggers the error when the expression is **true**. This almost certainly means that you need to negate the output of REGEX, as such:

```
NOT(REGEX( {!TSP_Code} , "TSP(?i)[a-z\\d]{6}-[a-z\\d]\\d"))
```

Comment: Got it what you saying, and i also want to do that like this will validate only when some value is there in field. if field is empty then this should not validate. Any idea on that?

Comment: @Salesfor_dev `NOT(OR(ISBLANK( ... ), REGEX( ... ) )` or `AND(NOT(ISBLANK( field ) ), NOT( REGEX( ... ) ) )` would work (these are equivalent via [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 0):

```
TSP([a-zA-Z0-9]){6}-([a-zA-Z0-9]){1}([0-9]){1}
```

Try wrappnig () around the square ones.

Tested it on : https://regexr.com/

Comment: The parentheses shouldn't make a difference.